# What term is used for the closing of a letter?

Tags: terminology, letter-writing, correspondence

**Salutation** is the term used to describe the beginning of a letter or other correspondence. What is the term used for the closing of a letter? Here are some examples: *Yours truly*, *Sincerely*, *Best wishes*, *Love*?

Searching for 'antonym of salutation'**[1](http://thesaurus.com/browse/salutation)** was not helpful.

EDIT: This need not be expressed as a single word. (Whatever is correct is fine, whether one word or a phrase!)

`1.` Citation (IEEE Style): **[Thesaurus.com, "salutation,"](http://thesaurus.com/browse/salutation)** in Roget's 21st Century Thesaurus, Third Edition.  Source location: Philip Lief Group 2009.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The symmetrical term is *valediction*, but I don't suppose it's very much used.

Comment: I think that it IS used, or sought, more than we realize. This was just suggested to me as an illustration of the currency of *valediction* in current times  http://therealsouthkorea.wordpress.com/2009/03/06/whats-the-opposite-of-salutation-what-do-you-call-that-the-greeting-at-the-end-of-a-letteremail/  And I think that "symmetrical term" is the better way to describe it, instead of antonym. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you could refer to it as a 'sign-off' or 'statement signing off' in more common tongue.

Comment: I agree it is not much used, though it probably should be!  *"The day was breaking. In the disfigured street he left me, with a kind of valediction,
And faded on the blowing of the horn."*

Comment: Valediction is used in US English. Closing or Complimentary Closing is used in British & International English. Neither terms are in common everyday use since the mass-cultural move to email. I was taught both in formal letter-writing classes 40 years ago (which no longer exist for obvious reasons).

Comment: "Valediction" is not used much, but "valedictorian" is the same word and is much more common.

Answer (score 12):

I've only ever heard that line referred to as the *closing*.

If we're to go by one of the many virtually identical [letter diagrams](http://www.mhschool.com/ss/ca/images/img_g3_personalletter.gif) available online, that usage is confirmed, although some call it the *complimentary closing*.

Barrie's suggestion of *valediction* is technically correct, but so far as I can tell it's not really in use.

Comment: I would suggest they come in word pairs, i.e. salutation-valediction and opening-closing. When using one of the terms in a word pair it would be proper form to also use the other (although proper form is often not called for, of course).

Comment: @Bjorn: I don't think it's so much that "proper form" isn't called for; it's really just that *valediction* is (for whatever reason) **vastly** more obscure than *salutation* in practice.

Comment: I have also only ever seen/heard *closing* or (less frequently) *complimentary closing* for this in actual use. Thus, I consider this absolutely the right answer for the literal (descriptivist) question in the subject line. Even Barrie concedes *valediction* isn't much used.

Comment: @Feral Oink: But that's my point exactly. I *specifically* noted your question, and your question asks what term *is used*.  The answer is: *Closing* is the term used for the closing of a letter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2008/discussion-between-john-y-and-feral-oink)