# What's the opposite of a greeting?

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What term is used for the closing of a letter?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51792/what-term-is-used-for-the-closing-of-a-letter)

You use a greeting when you need to open communication with someone, but is there a word for when you need to close communication?

for example,

note a / indicates a physical action (not just spoken words):

```
Greetings:  Hey, Hi, /salute, /wave, etc.

   ????  : Bye, See ya, /wave, etc.
```

Comment: maybe a Leaving?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a host of words for this:

> goodbye, farewell, leave-taking, adieu, arrivederci, au revoir, sayonara

cornbread sums them up all in *valediction*.

Comment: I'll upvote this one rather than cornbread's. You've both given the "correct" word *(valediction)*. But if, for example, I was at a party with my partner, and I wanted to leave, I'd probably say *"We need to say our **goodbyes**"* - so your first alternative matches my idea of the best word in common parlance. That's for "in-person" contexts - I'd just call the words written at the end of an item of correspondence the *sign-off*.

Comment: I must have misread OP's op as I thought OP sought merely written closings.

Answer (score 8):

Wikipedia calls it a *[valediction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valediction)*.  I'd just call it a *closing*.

> A valediction (derivation from Latin vale dicere, 'to say
> farewell'),[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valediction) or complimentary close in American English,[2] is an
> expression used to say farewell, especially a word or phrase used to
> end a letter or message,[3][4] or the act of saying parting words-
> whether brief, or extensive.
>
> For the greetings counterpart to valediction, see salutation.

Answer (score 8):

In a letter, most people call it "a closing".

In person, most people call it "goodbyes".

"Valediction" is a perfectly good word but rarely used in common speech.

Answer (score 3):

In letters, it's called a *complimentary close*.

This guy collects them in a database:
http://www.clarksco.com/trivia/regards/index.php

You could also use the word *farewells* — [one definition being, a parting salutation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Farewell)

Comment: The clarksco.com website doesn't exist anymore. Do you know if it has moved, so we could replace the URL?

Comment: @FeralOink, No, I don't know. Sorry.

Comment: This is a pretty good collection of phrases to use in a complimentary close to replace the link above that no longer works: https://www.letters.org/letter-closings.html