# What is the "gratitude" at the end of the letter or post called?

Tags: terminology, letter-writing, valediction

What is the "gratitude" at the end of a letter or post called in English?

For example:

```
Hi everyone,      <--- salutation

bla bla bla       <--- body

Thanks in advance <--- what is that called?
```

Comment: So tempted to add the correct tag, but I restrained myself.

Comment: It's called a "***valediction***". I know this question is a dupe, but can't find the original from my phone right now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all!

As @Dan_Bron and @Mari-Lou_A suggested - the answer is **valediction**.

Original question can be found [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51792/what-term-is-used-for-the-closing-of-a-letter)